# What is the intuitive meaning of "conspiracy" in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, intuition

Assuming very little number-theoretic background from my part, could you please explain me what is the intuitive meaning behind "conspiracy" in number theory? There is no formal entry on Wikipedia and I found the term in [Terence Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/) and if my memory is correct I believe he touched upon it in a YouTube video. More specifically, I am having trouble understanding the following excerpt from the same blog:

> Philosophically, one of the main reasons why it is so hard to control
>   the distribution of the primes is that we do not currently have too
>   many tools with which one can rule out “conspiracies” between the
>   primes, in which the primes (or the von Mangoldt function) decide to
>   correlate with some structured object (and in particular, with a
>   totally multiplicative function) which then visibly distorts the
>   distribution of the primes. For instance, one could imagine a scenario
>   in which the probability that a randomly chosen large integer ${n}$ is
>   prime is not asymptotic to ${\frac{1}{\log n}}$ (as is given by the
>   prime number theorem), but instead to fluctuate depending on the phase
>   of the complex number ${n^{it}}$ for some fixed real number ${t}$, thus
>   for instance the probability might be significantly less than ${1/\log
> > n}$ when ${t \log n}$ is close to an integer, and significantly more than
>   ${1/\log n}$ when ${t \log n}$ is close to a half-integer. This would
>   contradict the prime number theorem, and so this scenario would have
>   to be somehow eradicated in the course of proving that theorem. In the
>   language of Dirichlet series, this conspiracy is more commonly known
>   as a zero of the Riemann zeta function at ${1+it}$.

Please note that my motivation is chiefly a philosophical interpretation than a number theoretic one, so it would be very helpful if the reasoning is directed in that way.

Thank you.

Comment: Related? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108000/1284. The "conspiracy" is that the summatory Liouville function does not behave exactly like a random walk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $N$ be a 100-digit even number. Pick $10^{96}$ odd numbers, uniformly at random, from among the integers up to $N$. The chances that among those $10^{96}$ numbers you can't find two that add up to $N$ are very, very close to zero - so close to zero that if it actually happened you might suspect that the numbers you chose had conspired with each other to avoid adding up to $N$.

Goldbach's conjecture says that every even number exceeding $4$ is a sum of two odd primes. The number of odd primes up to the $100$-digit number $N$ exceeds $10^{96}$, so, speaking informally, we say it would take a conspiracy among the primes for Goldbach's conjecture to fail for that number $N$.

So that's what "conspiracy" means; some situation that is extremely unlikely to happen on any mild assumption about the distribution of the primes could only happen if there is a conspiracy among the primes.

Comment: The last paragraph illuminates. So basically if 'heads' show up all the time when a coin is tossed, we can say that the event is "conspired", correct?